# Android Studio gradle download without progress update

Tags: android, gradle

[image]

Today, I run "Gradle Sync" through Android Studio, and it spent almost 3hours at this screen.

From the command line, it goes fine!

How is this happening? What is the real progress of this progress?

Answer (score 0):

From my experience:
Check if you have RAM, 8gb ram is required but sometimes that's not enough, emulator and VCS take a good amount of ram.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Studio#System_requirements

it says 4gb ram minimum and 8gb recommended but i have 8gb ram and it's seems they mean 8gb ram free and allocated for android studio and emulator.

I have disabled VCS but still 6gb is not enough for a smooth use.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I got 16gb ram :D